# spring autowiring with processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I have following situation. There is POJO which has autowired implementation of an interface, using some spring magic as shown bellow. However this dependency doesn't get resolved if creation of channels is managed via spring bean. It only works if POJO factory creates channels. Example bellow.

```
@Controller
public class Test{


    @RequestMapping(value = "/load", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String testConfiguration() {

        // this is pojo and here it works, channels within have wired interface implementation                                          
        StaticFactory.getChannels(null);

        // if i call same method within spring managed bean (@Service) 
        // then it doesnt work


        System.out.println("channels created");

        return "alive";

    }

}
```

Created Channels are POJO but they have autowired interface implementation, which should be enabled with the following in constructor:

```
public DummyChannel() {

    // enables dependency injection of spring managed beans into POJO
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);    

}

public class StaticFactory {

    public static List<SmppChannel> getChannels(Map<ChannelMode, Integer> channelsDefinition) {

        List<SmppChannel> dummyChannels = new ArrayList<>();

        DummyChannel d = new DummyChannel();

        System.out.println("here");

        dummyChannels.add(new DummyChannel());

        return dummyChannels;
    }

}
```

Now, this thing works if i have non-spring managed Factory. Regardless if mentioned factory is static or not when it creates channels, they have properly wired interface implementation.
However, if i copy paste exactly same code form the factory into Spring managed Bean annotated with @Service, wired dependency is null in created channel.
Could somebody tell me what am i missing here, why things get injected when the factory of channels is not managed by the Spring ?

**Edit Solution: //**  Okay, so the problem is in the fact that DummyChannels enable autowiring support in constructor while Spring beans are still not loaded. It is working if i do this within method that should access autowired service rather then the constructor of DummyChannel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled `annotation-config` and `component-scan` in your xml or java configuration? Is the class that you want to inject annotated with `@Service` or `@Resource`?

Are you building a Web Service with JAX-WS? If yes, then I think your class (the one doing the autowiring) must implement `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` so that Spring's IoC container can handle the injection.

Comment: I have enabled component scan, and the class implementing the interface i wish to inject is annotated with @Service. Injection works as long as factory isn't spring managed e.g. if it is POJO too.

Comment: i think that the issue is in argument "this" in:     SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this); when the caller is spring managed bean.

Comment: the argument "this" is good. Ok, so my understanding is that your class `DummyChannel` needs to autowire your service implementation, right? What is your need to use [SpringBeanAutowiringSupport](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/context/support/SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.html)? You are using `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` in `DummyChannel`  because within that class you want to resolve a `@autowired`  annotation?

Comment: This dummy channel should autowire some @Service implementation of interface. Yeah i am using SpringBeanAutowiringSupport to resolve this dependency

Comment: I would like to have different factories which i could inject depending on the profile, such as the development or test. Hence i tried to have these factory beans managed by spring.

Comment: just an idea: don't let `DummyChannel` resolve the `@autowired` bean (you create `DummyChannel` instances with the `new` keyword, I fear this could be troublesome), let your factory class resolve the `@autowired` bean. Make sure you don't create the factory with `new` and place the line `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this)` in a `@PostConstruct public void init() {...}` method within your factory. Now use your autowired bean as a constructor parameter to create `DummyChannel` instances with the `new` keyword. It could work... if not, post some more code :-)