# How to get an instance of @Component in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've a @Container class called RegistrationValidator that depends on a spring @Repository. Getting an instance of it in a service or another container through autowiring is fine, but I need access to it in a regular POJO. How can I get an instance of this validator without converting all POJOs to @Container or @Service objects. Is there a way to add a static getInstance method within the RegistrationValidator that returns an instance.

```
package core.dao.validator;

import core.dao.Registration;
import core.repository.RegistrationRepository;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

/**
 * Validates the Registration DAO.
 *
 * @author Srini Katragadda
 */
@Component
public class RegistrationValidator implements Validator {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RegistrationValidator.class);
    private static final int MAX_SIZE = 255;

    private final RegistrationRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    RegistrationValidator(RegistrationRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return Registration.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
        Registration registration = (Registration) obj;

        // Validate Message Id
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "messageId", "messageId.empty");
        if (registration.getMessageId() != null &&
                registration.getMessageId().length() > MAX_SIZE) 
            errors.rejectValue("messageId", "Size greater than " + MAX_SIZE);

        // Validate for duplicate messageId information
        if (hasDuplicateMessageIdInDatabase(registration)) {
            errors.rejectValue("callouts", "Database has duplicate registration with messageId.");
        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if there is duplicate messageId in database.
     */
    private boolean hasDuplicateMessageIdInDatabase(Registration adsRegistration) {
        return (repository.findByMessageId(adsRegistration.getMessageId()) != null);
    }
}
```

Here is where I need an instance of that validator. Checkout the Builder.build() method which is passing an instance of validator to a utility method. This worked fine until I needed to autowire a @Repository in RegistrationValidator. Now I need to pass the instance of repository to be able to construct the validator and was wondering how without making the DAO itself another component and autowiring it with RegistrationValidator.

```
package core.dao;

import core.dao.validator.RegistrationValidator;
import core.util.ValidatorUtil;
import core.util.ToString;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

/**
 * The data access object that holds the information of an Registration.
 */
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public final class Registration {

    private String id;
    private String messageId;
    private String version;

    public Registration() {
    }

    private Registration(Builder builder) {
        this.id = builder.id;
        this.messageId = builder.messageId;
        this.version = builder.version;
    }

    public static Builder getBuilder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }

    public void setMessageId(String messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    /**
     * Builder pattern makes the object easier to construct in one line.
     */
    public static class Builder {

        private String id;

        private String messageId;

        private String version;

        private Builder() {}

        public Builder id(String id) {
            this.id = id;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder messageId(String messageId) {
            this.messageId = messageId;
            return this;
        }


        public Builder version(String version) {
            this.version = version;
            return this;
        }

        public Registration build() {
            Registration entry = new Registration(this);
            return (Registration) ValidatorUtil.validate(entry, new RegistrationValidator());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is ValidatorUtil.validate code for completeness.

```
public static Object validate(Object entry, org.springframework.validation.Validator customValidator) {
    Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(entry, entry.getClass().getName());
    customValidator.validate(entry, errors);
    if (errors == null || errors.getAllErrors().isEmpty())
        return entry;
    else {
        LOGGER.error(errors.toString());
        throw new InvalidDataException(errors.getAllErrors().toString(), errors);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use it's instance in a POJO? Can you show the usecase? May be that could be moved to service class.

Comment: Updated question with more info. Please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Ideally I would not have the `validate()` method talk to DB to verify duplicates. It should simply validate the state of the object (whether it is in valid state or not). That's it. After that, it's the job of service layer to verify whether the fully constructed and validated object is duplicate or not.

Comment: Yeah, may be that's what I will do to keep it clean. Having all the validation at one place has some merit, but not at the expense of polluting the code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You could autowire spring bean into pojo with the SpringBeanAutowiringSupport, in the following way:

```
public class Pojo {

@Autowired
private RegistrationRepository repository

    public void methodWhichRequiresBean() {

        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);

        repository.doStuff()

     }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: repository.doStuff() is returning NullPointerException, so repository is not initialized.

Comment: Is Pojo perhaps created before spring initialized this bean ?

Comment: I had sort of similar issue, in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656947/spring-autowiring-with-processinjectionbasedoncurrentcontextthis    My problem was that i used SpringBeanAutowiringSupport in constructor while beans still weren't created. My pojos were created within some Spring managed factory injected into another spring service - anyway problem was with Pojos/bean creation time.